# Error : this.attr is not a function when trying to get the position of an element using Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

Im new to Rapahel and im trying to get the position of an element when its clicked.Please find the code snippet below.Its giving me an error saying **this.attr is not a function**.Im sure Im doing it wrong,please advise.

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>Raphael Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function initPage() {
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('holder'), 1200, 500); 
        var nodeHeader = paper.rect(100,100,150,50,10);
        nodeHeader.attr({  
                        gradient: '90-#6BAA3A-#409400',  
                        stroke: '#6BAA3A',  
                        'stroke-width': 1, 
                        cursor: "move" 
                        });
        nodeHeader.node.id='nodeHeader';
        nodeHeader.node.onclick = function(){
            alert(this.attr('x'));
        };
    };
    </script> 
        <div id="holder"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "this" object within an event context gives you the DOM node, not the Element object that wraps around it and contains Raphael's functionality. You can either re-use the previous Element variable you declared when creating it, or retrieve the Element object dynamically by ID:

```
nodeHeader.node.onclick = function(){

    // Re-use previous variable
    alert(nodeHeader.attr("x"));

    // Retrieve dynamically via ID
    alert(paper.getById("nodeHeader").attr("x"));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put the "onClick" handler directly onto the DOM object (the node) not the Raphael object itself. Thus as explained by Luke you receive the DOM object as the this pointer in the event handler. Have you put the click handler on the Raphael object you would have received the Raphael object in your click handler.

try this instead, and you will receive your Raphael object as the this pointer as expected:

```
nodeHeader.click(function(event) {
    console.log("%o, %o", this, event);
    alert(this.attr('x'));
});
```